# loading an image referenced in an array

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to store an image name in an array then have a UIImage load this image through referencing the array something like this

```
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[quizArray objectAtIndex:1]]];
```

the image is in the resource folder

thanks Chris

ps ... beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely possible.  However, when you say `the image is in the resource folder`, I'm assuming that means that you just want to get an image from your resources folder, then display it, correct?

If so, there's no need to stuff it in an array.  Just access it like this:

```
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage"]];
```

However, in your example you used `[quizArray objectAtIndex:1]` in combination with `imageNamed:`. Remember, `imageNamed:` only takes a string parameter, so passing an object to it will crash your application.

---

I would arrange your question in a different way.  Instead of using arrays, you'd be better off with using dictionaries.  Like this:

```
NSImage *image1 = [NSImage imageNamed:@"myimage"];
NSMutableDictionary *quizDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 @"What colour is the sky?","question",
                                 @"blue",@"answer",
                                 @"red",@"wrong1",
                                 @"green",@"wrong2",
                                 @"yellow",@"wrong3",
                                 image1,@"image",nil];
```

Then to access it, you can just use the key names, like this:

```
NSString *question = [quizDict objectForKey:@"question"];
NSString *correct = [quizDict objectForKey:@"answer"];
NSImage *image = [quizDict objectForKey:@"image"];
```

Comment: u r right it crashes what do i use instead of imageNamed i have it in an array as its for a random quiz and some questions are text and some images the questions are always at element 0 followed by four possible answers with the correct answer identified in the last element

Comment: Okay, slow down just a little bit.  You are saying that the image are *sometimes* at index 0, and sometimes not?  Can you kind of make it more clear?

Comment: where is it exactly?  Maybe it got lost in your comment.  Upload it to somewhere like http://pastie.org/ and poste the link here.

Comment: heres a bit of the array quizArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
     [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Q: What colour is the sky?", @"blue", @"Red", @"Green",@"Yellow",@"1", nil],
     [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Q: Wots my dogs it then gets randomised so the questions appear in a different order each time the quiz is started, the question is always at first element  i want to store an image in some  of the question elements in the array.i have it all working nice with just text just cant figure the image bit

Comment: Let me just put it this way:  That's quite honestly a bad method of organization for your data.  Let me suggest another way in my answer.

Comment: excellent thanks i will try it ... havnt got to dictionaries in my study book yet

Comment: No problem.  You'll find them (mostly) easy to use and nicer than arrays. :)  Also, the way Stack Overflow works is that if an answer solves your question, you select the check mark next to the answer.  It gives both of us points, and helps others too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it is possible. Additionaly, your code is correct too. App should load the second image in your array (indexes begin from **0**).

If you're a beginner you should look for some books or online tutorials for iOS programmers. For example, lynnda.com offers you some video tutorials. (I used one of them when I was a beginner too) :)